# Static website does not want to work with a simple POST endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, post

I've made a simple static website, with some `CSS` & `JS`:

[image]

If I run this with SpringBoot, everything works pretty well, even JS works.

Now, I want to add a simple POST endpoint:

```
@RestController
public class Generator {

    @RequestMapping(name = "/generator", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String payload(final GeneratorPayload payload) {
        System.out.println("This is your payload: " + payload.getFirstName());
        return "testresp";
    }

}
```

Which throws 
`org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported` when accessing the main page (I'm not even calling that endpoint), displaying an error.

If I delete the inner mapping `("/generator")`, everything works fine.

It's like he was overriding the default method and applies it to the index?
What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an error here:

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/generator", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

I've specified `name`, instead of `value` and the mapping was being attached to `"/"`.

The correct version:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generator", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```